# is there a size limit to individual fields in HTTP POST?

Tags: apache, http, post, http-post, jetty

I have an API for a file upload that expects a multipart form submission. But I have a customer writing a client and his system can't properly generate a `multipart/form-data` request. He's asking that I modify my API to accept the file in a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request, with the filename in one key/value pair and the contents of the file, base64 encoded, in another key/value pair.

In principle I can easily do this (tho I need a shower afterwards), but I'm worried about size limits. The files we expect in Production will be fairly large: 5-10MB, sometimes up to 20MB. I can't find anything that tells me about length limitations on individual key/value pair data inside a form POST, either in specs (I've looked at, among others, the [HTTP spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) and the [Forms spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)) or in a specific implementation (my API runs on a Java application server, Jetty, with an Apache HTTP server in front of it).

What is the technical and practical limit for an individual value in a key/value pair in a form POST?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are artificial limits, configurations, present on the HttpConfiguration class.  Both for maximum number of keys, and maximum size of the request body content.

In practical terms, this is a really bad idea.

You'll have a String, which uses 2-bytes per character for the Base64 data.
And you have the typical 33% overhead just being Base64.

They'll also have to utf8 urlencode the Base64 string for various special characters (such as "+" which has meaning in Base64, but is space " " in urlencoded form.  So they'll need to encode that "+" to "%2B").

So for a 20MB file you'll have ...

20,971,520 bytes of raw data, represented as 27,892,122 characters in raw Base64, using (on average) 29,286,728 characters when urlencoded, which will use 58,573,455 bytes of memory in its String form.

The decoding process on Jetty will take the incoming raw urlencoded bytes and allocate 2x that size in a String before decoding the urlencoded form.  So that's a 58,573,456 length java.lang.String (that uses 117,146,912 bytes of heap memory for the String, and don't forget the 29MB of bytebuffer data being held too!) just to decode that Base64 binary file as a value in a x-www-form-urlencoded String form.

I would push back and force them to use `multipart/form-data` properly.  There are tons of good libraries to generate that form-data properly.

If they are using Java, tell them to use the `httpmime` library from the Apache HttpComponents project (they don't have to have/use/install Apache Http Client to use the httpmime, its a standalone library).

**Alternative Approach**

There's nothing saying you have to use `application/x-www-form-urlecnoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

Offer a raw upload option via `application/octet-stream`

They use `POST`, and MUST include the following valid request headers ...

```
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: <whatever_size_the_content_is>
```

- `Connection: close` to indicate when the http protocol is complete.
- `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` means Jetty will not process that content as request parameters and will not apply charset translations to it.
- `Content-Length` is required to ensure that the entire file is sent/received.

Then just stream the raw binary bytes to you.

This is just for the file contents, if you have other information that needs to be passed in (such as filename) consider using either the query parameters for that, or a custom request header (eg: `X-Filename: secretsauce.doc`)

On your servlet, you just use HttpServletRequest.getInputStream() to obtain those bytes, and you use the `Content-Length` variable to verify that you received the entire file.

Optionally, you can make them provide a SHA1 hash in the request headers, like `X-Sha1Sum: bed0213d7b167aa9c1734a236f798659395e4e19` which you then use on your side to verify that the entire file was sent/received properly.

Comment: Thanks, Joakim, for the detailed response! I'd completely forgotten that the payload would be additionally url-encoded (even though it says so right in the media type!) And I just store the file, I have no need to try to put it all in memory. I'm pretty stunned the client can't handle multipart -- they're on a major enterprise software platform I can't name, and this technology has been stable for almost 20 years. And the code on my side works! I'll see what I can do about pushing back; I don't relish asking them to properly provide a raw bytestream either ;-)